# Do I need @Singleton if bound with asEagerSingleton?

Tags: guice

I have a component I want to be managed by Guice:-

```
class MyComponent {
```

I can successfully have Guice instantiate it on app startup, and I want it available immediately and also as a Singleton. This works:-

```
bind(classOf[MyComponent]).asEagerSingleton
```

My question is -> do I need the annotation on the class, or is it superfluous in this case?

```
@Singleton
class MyComponent {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

short answer: No - you don't need the Singleton annotation in that case. The bean will be a singleton. However, read on to know why this isn't the same.

Longer answer:

This depends a bit on your usecase. First of all:

```
Singleton != EagerSingleton
```

An eager singleton is instantiated when you bind it. A singleton is instantiated once an instance is requested from guice. See this example:

```
public class SingletonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Injector createInjector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Test.class).asEagerSingleton();
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Start");
        Test instance = createInjector.getInstance(Test.class);
        System.out.println(instance);
        Test instance2 = createInjector.getInstance(Test.class);
        System.out.println(instance2);
    }

    public static class Test {

        public Test() {
            System.out.println("Constructor called");
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Constructor called
Start
test.guice.SingletonTest$Test@44c8afef
test.guice.SingletonTest$Test@44c8afef
```

If you don't bind it as eager singleton, it will still be a singleton, however the constructor is called when you are requesting the instance here:

```
Test instance = createInjector.getInstance(Test.class);
```

binding as singleton, or annotating as Singleton has the same effect.

Note: You don't have an eager singleton annotation, though there are frameworks that add that functionality.

Now why would you want to use annotations? A lot of frameworks are switching to bean discovery. This means, that you can eventually eliminate Modules and have Guice simply scan for your beans.

Now, if you had your bindings defined in a module, you will have to go through them and annotate your classes. If you forget some, your code will likely not work.

If you had them annotated with the correct annotations, you will be able to use classpath scanning (or similar mechanisms) to instantiate your objects.

Running my test code with singleton bindings/and or annotations results in matching output. So a binding as singleton, and a bean annotated with a singleton annotation behave same.